# How do i get a list of Group Policy Settings / Preferences in Powershell

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, group-policy

I want to fetch of a GPO all settings / preferences.
There is nothing about GPPs on the internet, and I struggle with a solution.

Comment: take a look at `gpresult /r /v` or `gpresult /?`.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey not what OP needs. gpresult will give a client result for the GPO applied to your user. In order to get GPO for all settings, you can use powershell to export the entire GPO to an .xml file which in essence gives the settings. When using Powershell to work with GPO settings, .xml files is always the way to go.

Comment: `Backup-GPO -Name "Name of Policy" -Path C:\MyFolder` for export, `Import-GPO -BackupGpoName "Name of Policy" -TargetName "New GPO Name" -Path C:\MyFolder` for new gpo based on import.

Comment: @LPChip - thank you for the info! i am on a win10pro system and the `Backup-Gpo` cmdlet is not available there.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Yes, this needs to be run from the domain controller. You always need to do this from the DC otherwise you never will get all settings. If you are a system administrator, you can use enter-pssession to connect to the DC remotely first and run the powershell command through a tunnel.